# Can we change the Completion Email Subject using DocuSign Custom Branding option?

Tags: docusignapi

Can we change the Completion Email Subject using DocuSign Custom Branding option? We can change the Email Blurb content using Email Resources XML file. But there is no option to change the Email Subject using Email Resources XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this through the Email Resource file under Branding.  Try this:

1. Login to your developer sandbox at demo.docusign.net
2. Click your profile icon in top right, then go to `Preferences -> Branding`.
3. Select the branding profile you are currently using, or create a new one.
4. On a given brand, select the `Resources` tab, then select the Email Resource file.
5. Search for this string in your Email resource file:

   ```
   <data name="RecipientEnvelopeComplete_Subject">Completed: [[SubjectInput]]</data>
   ```

Try changing that to the new subject text you'd like and that should do the trick.